# dealing with riak datatypes in postcommit hooks

Tags: erlang, riak, post-commit-hook, crdt

I am wanting to implement a postcommit hook for riak that decrements a counter in a map in another bucket. However I am having a bit of trouble dealing with the riak datatypes.

Here is me attempting from `riak console`:

```
(riak@127.0.0.1)9>{ok, C} = riak:local_client().
{ok,{riak_client,['riak@127.0.0.1',undefined]}}
(riak@127.0.0.1)10>{ok, Obj} = C:get({<<"product">>, <<"default">>}, <<"1">>).
{ok,{r_object,{<<"product">>,<<"default">>},
          <<"1">>,
          [{r_content,{dict,5,16,16,8,80,48,
                            {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...},
                            {{[],[],[],[],
                              [[<<"dot">>|{<<"#\tþù"...>>,{...}}]],
                              [],[],[],[],[],...}}},
                      <<69,2,0,0,0,11,114,105,97,107,95,100,116,95,109,97,112,
                        77,1,...>>}],
          [{<<35,9,254,249,108,41,151,242>>,{1,63593788980}}],
          {dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...},
                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...}}},
          undefined}}
(riak@127.0.0.1)11> Mp = riak_object:get_value(O3).
<<69,2,0,0,0,11,114,105,97,107,95,100,116,95,109,97,112,
  77,1,131,80,0,0,0,206,120,1,203,96,...>>
(riak@127.0.0.1)12> MpP = riak_dt_map:from_binary(Mp).
{error,invalid_binary}
```

`product` bucket datatype is set to `map`. Each object stored should have a counter called `quantity` which I'd like to decrement.

However I cannot find any documentation or sample code dealing with datatypes in a pre or post commit context. (actually examples of any kind are few). I've been reading the source of [riak_client](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/2.0/src/riak_client.erl) and [riak_dt_map](https://github.com/basho/riak_dt/blob/2.0/src/riak_dt_map.erl) but I am new to erlang so I'm making slow progress and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The r_object that you have there does not directly hold a riak_dt_map, rather it holds a riak_kv_crdt that contains a riak_dt_map that in turn contains your counter.

To update the counter, you would need to first get the context from the map:

```
{{Context,_},_}=riak_kv_crdt:value(Obj,riak_dt_map).
```

Then build the operation to increment the counter named <<"name">> in the map contained in the CRDT:

```
Op = {crdt_op,riak_dt_map,{update,[{update,{<<"name">>,riak_dt_emcntr},increment}]},Context}.
```

And then apply that operation to the CRDT, providing the actor ID you want to use to update the vclock/version vector:

```
NewObj = riak_kv_crdt:update(Obj,Actor,Op).
```

The result should be another r_object that is ready to be sent back for storage.